# web3.eth.getBalance(...).then is not a function

Tags: web3js, etherscan

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/5db0a2fb8a8948fdbe57bb19eecb5674'));

web3.eth.getBalance('0x742d35Cc6634C0532925a3b844Bc454e4438f44e').then((res)=>console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(res,'ether')))
```

and the following is the error I'm getting after running the above code.

```
 web3.eth.getBalance(...).then is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\gitty\app.js:15:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use callback for getBalance function. kindly read [Document](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getbalance) .

```
 web3.eth.getBalance('0x742d35Cc6634C0532925a3b844Bc454e4438f44e',function(error,result){

    if(error){
       console.log(error)
    }
    else{
       console.log(result)
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

check for the Typo. web3.eth.getBalance.

while giving input wait get to autoselect then B, then web3 automatically enable the function. then it will work,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).